# Tensor has shape [?, 0] -- how to reshape to [?,]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, reshape, tensorflow-datasets

When `src` has shape `[?]`, `tf.gather(src, tf.where(src != 0))` returns a tensor with shape `[?, 0]`. I'm not sure how a dimension can have size 0, and I'm especially unsure how to change the tensor back. I didn't find anything in the documentation to explain this, either.

I tried to `tf.transpose(tensor)[0]`, but the first dimension of the transposed tensor has size 0 and cannot be accessed! What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [`tf.not_equal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/not_equal) to perform elementwise comparison on the tensor.

```
src = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=tf.int8)
tf.gather(src, tf.where(tf.not_equal(src, 0))).eval(session=tf.Session())

array([[1],
       [1]], dtype=int8)
```

You can also shorten this a bit and use [`tf.boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) instead of `tf.where` and `tf.gather`:

```
tf.boolean_mask(src, tf.not_equal(src, 0)).eval(session=tf.Session())
array([1, 1], dtype=int8)
```

Note the difference in the shape of the outputs.